# Dart is not matching Regex for some fullwidth characters

Tags: regex, dart

I'm trying to remove punctuations in Flutter and noticed that it is not removing the "！" character.

Tried it with dartpad.dev and it is working.

```
    void main(){
      var re = RegExp(r"[\uFF01-\uFF0F]");
      var string = '踊れ！';
      print(string.replaceAll(re, ''));
    }
```

Is this a problem with flutter?

Comment: I think it works here https://tio.run/##S0ksKvn/vyw/M0UhNzEzT0OzmksBDMoSixSKUhVsFYJS010rCjSKlKJjSt3cDAx1wZRbrJKmNZLS4pKizLx0oHL1Fzu6Hjf1vN/TqA6TLwBKlWhAVOgVpRbkJCanOubkaBSl6iioq2tCzan9/x8A Perhaps try isUnicode https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/RegExp-class.html